# tagsinput only shows not found

Tags: typeahead.js, bootstrap-tags-input

It worked at first, but it gives all the data from the table. I tried to change something to suggest only the related names but when I returned it to my original code it stopped working.

```
$(function(){

         // constructs the suggestion engine
        var shoppableBrands = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace('name'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
             remote: {
                // url: 'tagToText.data('api')+'/%QUERY%','
        url: '//staging.sap.com/shoppable_brands/api',

                wildcard: '%QUERY',
                rateLimitBy: 'debounce',
                rateLimitWait: 300,
            }
        });
                shoppableBrands.initialize();

                $('#bloodhound .typeahead').tagsinput({
                    //maxTags:tagLimit,
                  //tagClass: 'label label-info '+singleTag,
                    confirmKeys: [13, 188],
                    itemValue: 'id',
                    itemText: 'name',
                    typeaheadjs: {
                        limit: 50,
                        hint:false,
                        source: shoppableBrands.ttAdapter(),
                        templates: {
                            suggestion: function(data){
                                var name = data.name;
                                return '<div class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable" title="'+name+'" >\
                                '+name+'</div>';
                            },


                         notFound : function(){
                                return '<div class="tt-suggestion" title="Not Found" >No Results Found</div>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                $('input#shoppable_brand_name').on('itemAdded', function(event) {
                    var type = event.item;
                    $('#shoppable_brand_type').val(type.type);
                    console.log(type.type);
                });



                $('#bloodhound .typeahead').on('beforeItemAdd', 

function(event) {
                       if($(this).data('limit') == 1) $(this).tagsinput('removeAll');
                    });

});
```

Comment: What stopped working?

Comment: it does not suggest data anymore, but the api is working. it only shows the 'no results found'